# Taking ownership of all the files in one go

Tags: custom

I have a library having 8788 items. When I go to manage no check in version files and try to take ownership by selecting all the documents , it is throwing the error. I am not sure how many items are there in the library exactly which are in no check in version mode. We tried CSOM for this , but no luck. Can anyone suggests on the same.?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If server side is an option, you can try [SPCheckedOutFile.TakeOverCheckOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcheckedoutfile.takeovercheckout.aspx)

```
IList<SPCheckedOutFile> files = library.CheckedOutFiles;
foreach (SPCheckedOutFile file in files)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-25} {2}", 
          file.DirName, file.LeafName, file.CheckedOutBy);
     file.TakeOverCheckOut();
}
```